# What is the bug here in this C code and why?

Tags: c

I came across this in an assessment and I need to find the bug and explain why.

```
int process(int, int*, int*); 

int example10(int in) 
{
    int *buffer1 = (int*)malloc(1000 * sizeof(int));
    if (!buffer1)
        return -1;

    int *buffer2 = (int*)malloc(2000 * sizeof(int));
    if (!buffer2)
        return -1;

    int retVal = process(in, buffer1, buffer2);

    free(buffer1);
    free(buffer2);

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: @LeatherFace http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26637725/edit

Comment: actually it's worse than that in the webpage! and that's everything they've mentioned!

Comment: It's **not urgent** for us.

Comment: Something is clearly wrong with the `#include`.

Comment: @Deduplicator indeed and sorry for bothering you, sir.

Comment: The easiest fix, which is also the most performant, would be simply coalescing the allocations.

Comment: @Deduplicator I concur. `buffer = malloc(3000 * sizeof *buffer);` , throwing out `buffer2`, and just passing `buffer, buffer+1000` as the final two parameters to `process` would make the most sense to me.

Comment: Actually it was the memory leak and thanks for your help @Deduplicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are freeing `buffer1` and `buffer2` only when  both `if` condition got passed. What if first `if` condition got passed and second `if` condition got failed. There will be memory leak in that case. Therefore free the `buffer1` in second `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If the second malloc fails you return from the function and don't free the memory from the first malloc call.

```
if (!buffer2)
{
    //free( buffer1 ) ;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @JJII Please take the time to format your question correctly. If any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: Will do I need 7 more minutes for that :)

Answer (score 1):

It is the memory leak in case of failure in second call to malloc: you don't call free on buffer1 then. Also the first line is incorrect directive for preprocessor, however we don't know if this is deliberately malformed or is it just your urgency.